# turnoff screenshot in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have created application in robot framework and want to disable screenshot.

Selenium2Library tried  run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot but taking screenshot for success case .

I need to stop taking screenshot for both success and failure case

Comment: so you DO NOT want to take screenshots? So remove lines that take screenshots

Answer (score 0):

To stop the default behavior of creating a screenshot on a selenium failure, change a flag during the import of the library:

```
Library    SeleniumLibrary    run_on_failure=NOTHING
```

And if you want to take away that capability entirely, even when a user calls the corresponding keyword in a case, you can override the keyword to do nothing:

```
Captures Page Screenshot
    [Documentation]    Not allowed.
    No Operation
```

With robotframework'scoping rules such keyword will take precedence over the library's one.